# How to break out in red console?

Tags: red

I have a long loop in a script I debug with

```
some code
ask "..."
next code
```

Crtl + C or Esc in Red console doesn't break out of it. I have to close the console and reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can help yourself with **break** or with any intended  error e.g.

```
 if "^[" = ask ".." [return]
```

Then you will fall back to the console

Answer (score 2):

Support for ESC in the input handler is [not implemented](https://github.com/red/red/issues/1844) yet.